# Articles Frontend Editing Issue: Field required: Category

Tags: articles, front-end, editing

I am doing some articles editing on the frontend, where I came across an issue. Some of the articles cannot be saved and Joomla returns the message "Field required: Category.

Of course the articles belong already to their category, but the issue for those specific articles is that the Category Select field is disabled in the form (showing their category- but disabled).

I just noticed that the language select is also disabled for those articles.

```
<select id="jform_catid" name="" class="inputbox" required="" aria-required="true" disabled="disabled">
```

What could cause the select field to get the disabled attribute for some random articles?

Comment: Same problem with a J! 3.3.3 and 3.3.2. The site is multilingual and i think you are right. It seems to appear when article is associated with corresponding article in another language.

Comment: This has now been solved in 3.3.x:
See: https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/pull/4062

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I have sorted out the conditions that make this issue appear, although I have not dive into the code yet.

Just for information, this is a Joomla 3.3.3 multilingual website.

The issue appears when an article has association with the corresponding article of the second language.

Can anyone else test to see if he can replicate the issue?
If I have time, I will try to investigate the code to see if I can come with further information.

#### Update

This proved to be a bug as seen here: [github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/pull/4062](https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/pull/4062)

Comment: For some reason I could not override the line 374 so I did change it in the core file which is working.