# Upgraded to 3.3: can't save in Frontend anymore ("category field required")

Tags: joomla-3.3.x, front-end

I can't edit anymore in the frontend. Each time I want to apply my changes I get an error "Field required: Category". Any idea how to solve this?

EDIT: this question has already been asked [here](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/3773/articles-frontend-editing-issue-field-required-category)

Comment: Is it multi-lingual website?

Comment: yes its a multi-lingual

Comment: http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/3773/articles-frontend-editing-issue-field-required-category

Comment: @FFrewin thanks a lot! I apologies for the duplicate

Answer (score 3):

There is known bug on the 3.3.3 version : 
Articles with multilanguage associations cannot be saved in frontend since 3.3.3. Error: "Warning: Field required: Category"

A ticket has been submitted [here](http://joomlacode.org/gf/project/joomla/tracker/&action=TrackerItemEdit&tracker_item_id=24698/?action=TrackerItemEdit&tracker_item_id=34080&start=9125)

Comment: Oh man, I should not have updated to 3.3.3

Comment: any idea how to solve it?

Comment: @Giim - https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/pull/4062/files#diff-f66af5cac40d67f3a63762ceb0c8b8c3L377

Comment: Thanks @Lodder! I had to edit the core file, as the override didn't work